# Ricoh SP 400DN printer stats: is there a way to get the printer stats (number of pages printed)?

Tags: printer, stat

Having a **Ricoh SP 400DN** monochrome LED printer, **I need to know how many pages were printed**.

I browsed the printer menu, as well as the [documentation](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001065/0001065573/view/booklist/int/index_book.htm) but cannot find any way to print, nor display, the printer stats.
From the menu, the most I can display is the approximate level of remaining toner.

Is there a possibly undocumented feature to get the printer stats?

Answer (score 1):

The printer's configuration page details a lot of info about the printer, including the number of pages printed. To print the config page, do this:

> Press the [Menu] key, and then select the setting items using the
> [Down arrow key ] or [Up arrow key ] key.
>
> Select [Printer Features]  Press [OK]
>
> Select [List/Test Print]  Press [OK]
>
> Select [Config. Page]  Press [OK]
>
> Press [Print]

This comes from [Ricoh's support website>](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001065/0001065573/view/manual/int/0046.htm)

They also have a [page that explains the Config Page](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001065/0001065573/view/manual/int/0046.htm)

Comment: Thank you! That's it! How can I have missed that? Likely because the not so intuitive menu entries. The number of pages printed is on the first of the two printed pages: System Reference > Total counter.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to my question:

1. **Download a network driver** for the printer
   I downloaded the "PS V4 Driver for Universal Print" from [here](http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/re2/model/sp400/sp400.htm).

2. **Connect the printer to your network** (i.e. to your router) through its RJ45 network socket (Ethernet) and install the driver.
3. **Install the network driver**: during the install, **the local IP address will be displayed**. (In my case it was 192.168.1.232. The last block of digits may vary.) The install also let you print a test page, on which the local IP address will be printed.
4. Open a web brower and **access your printer through its local IP address**.
   `e.g. http://localhost/192.168.1.232`

That's it. A web page will be displayed, with some tabs. One of them displays the page count.